# How to tell if UIViewController's view is visible

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I have a tab bar application, with many views. Is there a way to know if a particular `UIViewController` is currently visible from within the `UIViewController`?  (looking for a property)

Comment: Related: [Getting the top most UIViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067692/getting-the-top-most-uiviewcontroller)

Answer (score 1217, accepted):

The view's [window property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622456-window) is non-nil if a view is currently visible, so check the main view in the view controller:

*Invoking the [view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621460-view) method causes the view to load (if it is not loaded) which is unnecessary and may be undesirable.  It would be better to check first to see if it is already loaded.  I've added the call to isViewLoaded to avoid this problem.*

```
if (viewController.isViewLoaded && viewController.view.window) {
    // viewController is visible
}
```

Since iOS9 it has became easier:

```
if viewController.viewIfLoaded?.window != nil {
    // viewController is visible
}
```

---

Or if you have a UINavigationController managing the view controllers, you could check its [visibleViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621862-visibleviewcontroller) property instead.

Comment: The one issue with a UINavigationController's visibleViewControllee property is the case where your visibleViewController presents a modal view controller. In that case, the modal view becomes the visibleViewController, which may be undesirable. How would you handle that?

Comment: This is probably obvious to everyone, but for me the code had to be self.isViewLoaded && self.view.window

Comment: Note that in iOS 7, a navigation controller doesn't load a pushed view controller into memory right away.  This is different from iOS 6 where you could push a view controller and immediately see that navController.topViewController.isViewLoaded was true.

Comment: Be careful in generalizing this solution to other situations. For example, if you're using a UIPageViewController, views for UIViewControllers who are not the current page may still have a non-nil window property because they are being rendered off-screen. In this case, I've had success making my own 'isCurrentlyVisible' property which gets set in viewDidAppear and viewDidDisappear.

Comment: @Moshe in that case, use `topViewController`.

Comment: Swift way:  if (self.isViewLoaded() && self.view.window != nil ) {

Comment: Please note that this answer doesn't say anything about the real visibility. For example, if the app is in background above IF statement will say YES while view is not really visible.

Comment: this only worked for me in **viewDidAppear**. When I added this to *viewWillAppear* self.view.window != nil always came up nil

Comment: does viewController.viewIfLoaded?.window work when you're using a scene manifest (UISceneSession)?

Comment: Does not work correctly for custom containers, like Parchment

Comment: Thanks. My music app share AVAudioPlayer playing state on a container view and presented VC, when user take on/off their Airpod, I want to change state only on the visible one.

Answer (score 91):

Here's @progrmr's solution as a `UIViewController` category:

```
// UIViewController+Additions.h

@interface UIViewController (Additions)

- (BOOL)isVisible;

@end


// UIViewController+Additions.m

#import "UIViewController+Additions.h"

@implementation UIViewController (Additions)

- (BOOL)isVisible {
    return [self isViewLoaded] && self.view.window;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 57):

There are a couple of issues with the above solutions.  If you are using, for example, a `UISplitViewController`, the master view will always return true for

```c
if(viewController.isViewLoaded && viewController.view.window) {
    //Always true for master view in split view controller
}
```

Instead, take this simple approach which seems to work well in most, if not all cases:

```c
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    //We are now invisible
    self.visible = false;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    //We are now visible
    self.visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Is this still true in xCode 7.1.1? The master in my UISplitViewController is returning NO for viewController.view.window. I may be doing something wrong, but I am pretty sure this is the case.

Answer (score 46):

For those of you looking for a **Swift 2.2** version of the answer:

```
if self.isViewLoaded() && (self.view.window != nil) {
     // viewController is visible
}
```

and **Swift 3**:

```
if self.isViewLoaded && (self.view.window != nil) {
         // viewController is visible
}
```

Comment: Not sure why but I found that doing self.view.window != nil causes it to never work even when self.isViewLoaded is true. Once removed, it works fine.

Comment: this only worked for me in viewDidAppear. When I added this to viewWillAppear self.view.window != nil always came up nil

Answer (score 35):

For over-full-screen or over-context modal presentation, "is visible" could mean it is on top of the view controller stack or just visible but covered by another view controller.

To check if the view controller "is the top view controller" is quite different from "is visible", you should check the view controller's navigation controller's view controller stack.

I wrote a piece of code to solve this problem:

```
extension UIViewController {
    public var isVisible: Bool {
        if isViewLoaded {
            return view.window != nil
        }
        return false
    }

    public var isTopViewController: Bool {
        if self.navigationController != nil {
            return self.navigationController?.visibleViewController === self
        } else if self.tabBarController != nil {
            return self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController == self && self.presentedViewController == nil
        } else {
            return self.presentedViewController == nil && self.isVisible
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice post! FYI `isViewLoaded` is a property since Swift 3.0.

Answer (score 28):

You want to use the `UITabBarController`'s `selectedViewController` property. All view controllers attached to a tab bar controller have a `tabBarController` property set, so you can, from within any of the view controllers' code:

```
if([[[self tabBarController] selectedViewController] isEqual:self]){
     //we're in the active controller
}else{
     //we are not
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the view controller is contained inside a navigation controller and that controller is added to the tab bar controller. The call to selectedViewController will return the navigation controller and not the current view controller.

Comment: @AntonHolmberg in that case, get the visible view controller like this: `((UINavigationController *)self.tabBarController.selectedViewController).visibleViewController`

Comment: Or even use 'self.tabBarController.selectedIndex' property if we've gone this far.

Answer (score 14):

I made a swift extension based on @progrmr's answer.

It allows you to easily check if a `UIViewController` is on screen like so:

```
if someViewController.isOnScreen {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

The extension:

```
//
//  UIViewControllerExtension.swift
//

import UIKit

extension UIViewController{
    var isOnScreen: Bool{
        return self.isViewLoaded() && view.window != nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For my purposes, in the context of a container view controller, I've found that

```
- (BOOL)isVisible {
    return (self.isViewLoaded && self.view.window && self.parentViewController != nil);
}
```

works well.

Answer (score 6):

I use this small extension in **Swift 5**, which keeps it simple and easy to check for any object that is member of **UIView**.

```
extension UIView {
    var isVisible: Bool {
        guard let _ = self.window else {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Then, I just use it as a simple if statement check...

```
if myView.isVisible {
    // do something
}
```

I hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 5):

Good point that view is appeared if it's already in window hierarchy stack.
thus we can extend our classes for this functionality.

```swift
extension UIViewController {
  var isViewAppeared: Bool { viewIfLoaded?.isAppeared == true }
}

extension UIView {
  var isAppeared: Bool { window != nil }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

XCode 6.4, for iOS 8.4, ARC enabled

Obviously lots of ways of doing it.  The one that has worked for me is the following...

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isKeyWindow) BOOL keyWindow
```

This can be used in any view controller in the following way,

```
[self.view.window isKeyWindow]
```

If you call this property in `-(void)viewDidLoad` you get 0, then if you call this after `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` you get 1.

Hope this helps someone.  Thanks!  Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

if you're utilizing a UINavigationController and also want to handle modal views, the following is what i use:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

UIViewController* topMostController = self.navigationController.visibleViewController;
if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", class_getName([topMostController class])] isEqualToString:@"NAME_OF_CONTROLLER_YOURE_CHECKING_IN"]) {
    //is topmost visible view controller
}
```

Comment: I have found this way to be more reliable than the accepted answer, when a navigation controller is available. This can be shortened to:if ([self.navigationController.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {

Answer (score 3):

The approach that I used for a modal presented view controller was to check the class of the presented controller.  If the presented view controller was `ViewController2` then I would execute some code.

```
UIViewController *vc = [self presentedViewController];

if ([vc isKindOfClass:[ViewController2 class]]) {
    NSLog(@"this is VC2");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found those function in `UIViewController.h`.

```
/*
  These four methods can be used in a view controller's appearance callbacks to determine if it is being
  presented, dismissed, or added or removed as a child view controller. For example, a view controller can
  check if it is disappearing because it was dismissed or popped by asking itself in its viewWillDisappear:
  method by checking the expression ([self isBeingDismissed] || [self isMovingFromParentViewController]).
*/

- (BOOL)isBeingPresented NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
- (BOOL)isBeingDismissed NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);

- (BOOL)isMovingToParentViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
- (BOOL)isMovingFromParentViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

Maybe the above functions can detect the `ViewController` is appeared or not.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a navigation controller and just want to know if you are in the **active** and **topmost** controller, then use:

```
if navigationController?.topViewController == self {
    // Do something
}
```

This answer is based on [@mattdipasquale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242933/mattdipasquale)'s comment.

If you have a more complicated scenario, see the other answers above.

Comment: this will never be called if the app goes in background and then in foreground. I am looking for a solution where I can check if the view controller is visible to the user or not. User could background the app for a few days and when it comes back in foreground, I would like to  update UI. Please let me know if you can help.

Answer (score 2):

you can check it by `window` property

```
if(viewController.view.window){

// view visible

}else{

// no visible

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed this to check if the view controller is the current viewed controller, I did it via checking if there's any presented view controller or pushed through the navigator, I'm posting it in case anyone needed such a solution:

```
if presentedViewController != nil || navigationController?.topViewController != self {
      //Viewcontroller isn't viewed
}else{
     // Now your viewcontroller is being viewed 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Window:

```
window.isVisible
```

```
viewController.view.window?.isVisible ?? false
```

### View (macOS):

```
extension NSViewController {
    var isOnScreen: Bool {
        return ( self.isViewLoaded && view.window != nil )
    }
}
```