# ModalViewController doesn't save to core data?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, modalviewcontroller

iPad app fans:

I've got a modalviewcontroller designed to popup on a button tap so users can add notes or change data inputs. A table in the main window needs to be refreshed as changes to the database are made. The database incorporates a kind of advanced bookmark. I can create and delete database entries based on where users browse - no problem: I get the console report "saveContext KQVC line 203" and entries are quickly added into the table.

The modalviewcontroller even pops (on tapping the blue (>) detail icon also in each cell) with populated data of existing records. However the save button on the modalviewcontroller **just doesn't save**. (the delete function works great). Here's my code for the modalviewcontroller save button:

```
#import "PatternViewController.h"
#import "KnittingQueenViewController.h"

 @implementation PatternViewController
 @dynamic patternName, patternNotes, patternUrl, dateAdded;
 @synthesize patternA, patternView, knittingQueenViewController;

-(IBAction)save {
    [patternA setValue:patternName.text forKey:@"patternName"];
    [patternA setValue:patternUrl.text forKey:@"patternUrl"];
    [patternA setValue:patternNotes.text forKey:@"patternNotes"];
    dateAdded = [NSDate date];
    [patternA setValue:dateAdded forKey:@"dateAdded"];
    [patternA setValue:patternLabel.text forKey:@"patternLabel"];
    [patternA setValue:pngPath forKey:@"patternPhoto"];   

    [knittingQueenViewController saveContext];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and the saveContext method in the knittingqueenviewcontroller:

```
- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext]; 
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
         // error code goes in here
    }
    NSLog(@"saveContext KQVC line 203");
    [self refreshPatternsTable];
}
```

I get no errors, but no saved data either. My question: why isn't the method saveContext being called from the modalviewcontroller? Any suggestions you can offer would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your `save` method being called? Is `knittingQueenViewController` non-nil when it's called? Do the values of `patternA` look correct?

Comment: One of the first two questions here is almost certainly the issue.

Comment: @noa Answer to Q1: the method was being called but because the knittingQueenViewController was nil http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678180/how-to-check-if-a-specific-uiviewcontrollers-view-is-currently-visible tested per this answer. Answer to Q2: it was nil. So I've alloc init and now it crashes.

Comment: Allocating another one here won't help you – it doesn't have a references to your FetchedResultsController or ManagedObjectContext, for example. Where do you first allocate and initialize PatternViewController? From code? You probably need to add some code there that sets `knittingQueenViewController` to the already-created instance.

Comment: @noa Yes, it's from code. Here's the allocate and initialize of `PatternViewController` in `KnittingQueenViewController`. `-(IBAction)newPattern {
    PatternViewController *controller = [[PatternViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PatternViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];      
}` What would you suggest?

Comment: Cool. Just add `controller.knittingQueenViewController = self;` after the call to `initWithNibName`.

Comment: @noa nice. Method `saveContext` now gets called, but there's still no change to the table. Modifications aren't being committed...

Comment: How about Q3 / values of patternA in save?

Comment: @noa Now, we can edit and delete existing table entries using the `PatternViewController` ModalViewController. YEAH. But, creating a new entry from the `PatternViewController` goes through the `saveContext` but doesn't get added to the table. :( Suggestions?

Comment: @noa - works now. Thanks! I needed to add the reference to `    **knittingQueenViewController.**` in the lines for each item in the `[knittingQueenViewController.patternA setValue:patternName.text forKey:@"patternName"];` statement in the `save` method of the `PatternViewController`.