# Getting the top most UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

If I push view controllers and/or present modal view controllers on a `UINavigationController`, how can I find out what is the top most `UIViewController`? Or in my case, I want to know if a certain `UITableViewController` is the top most or not.

I tried using:

```
self.navigationController.topViewController == self
```

... but this doesn't work. I'm guessing that it's failing because I'm presenting modal view controllers on top of it and that the `topViewController` only keeps track of which views were pushed on the `UINavigationController` (as opposed to those that were presented modally).

Comment: Related: [How to tell if UIViewController's view is visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777438/how-to-tell-if-uiviewcontrollers-view-is-visible)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You want `visibleViewController`:

> The currently visible view can belong either to the view controller at the top of the navigation stack or to a view controller that was presented modally.

Comment: Could you please check this out: I want to know how to use visibleViewController to compare with the view that I am looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498880/how-to-determine-which-view-loads-on-returning-to-foreground-from-the-background

Comment: Note that this is only for `UINavigationController`; if you don't have one of these, you'll need to use other means.

Answer (score 23):

```
NSArray *viewContrlls=[[self navigationController] viewControllers];

[viewContrlls lastObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but it's still popular - that's why I'd like to post my best solution which handles different `UIViewController's` subclasses. At the same time you can extend functionality of this method by your custom "collection" controllers such as side menu.

```
extension UIWindow {

  var visibleViewController: UIViewController? {
    guard let rootViewController = rootViewController else {
      return nil
    }
    return visibleViewController(for: rootViewController)
  }

  private func visibleViewController(for controller: UIViewController) -> UIViewController {
    var nextOnStackViewController: UIViewController? = nil
    if let presented = controller.presentedViewController {
      nextOnStackViewController = presented
    } else if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController,
      let visible = navigationController.visibleViewController {
      nextOnStackViewController = visible
    } else if let tabBarController = controller as? UITabBarController,
      let visible = (tabBarController.selectedViewController ??
        tabBarController.presentedViewController) {
      nextOnStackViewController = visible
    }

    if let nextOnStackViewController = nextOnStackViewController {
      return visibleViewController(for: nextOnStackViewController)
    } else {
      return controller
    }
  }

}
```