# Is there a good way to check if the UIViewController is appearing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a method in a UIViewController to do things base on if it is currently appearing.
I can put a BOOL flag to switch YES/NO when the viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear is called but is there a better way/method to check?

Thanks.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777438/how-to-tell-if-uiviewcontrollers-view-is-visible

Answer (score 0):

The `viewDidAppear` method is your best bet.  I have seen some edge cases, though, where `viewDidAppear`/`viewDidDisappear` are not called depending on various factors.

Just because I enjoy the control and don't like any unknowns, I typically expose a method in my controllers that do all the setup when called and I would call this method when I know that  my controller is getting called into action.

A ***rough*** example:

```
@interface MyController: UIViewController
- (void)reset;
@end

@implementation MyController
- (void)reset
{
    //Set some defaults, do some logging, etc
}
- (void)viewDidAppear
{
     [self reset];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [self reset];
}
@end
```

Then...

```
@implementation SomeOtherController
- (void)someMethod
{
    [self.myController reset];

    //present self.myController using some logic

}
@end
```