# button pressed before appear on screem

Tags: objective-c, button, view

I'm making an app where you can post in your friends' facebook wall, the issue is that the friends are appearing in a independent UIView that I'm adding on the current view, during the while I'm waiting for the friends' view to appear, I'm touching the screen & the buttons have been pushed before the view is appearing on the screen, & even more than one button (when I have 'self.userinteractionenabled = NO;' when you press a button).
How could I solve this? I can set theView.userinteractionenabled = NO; when i'm initializing the view, & switch it to YES when the view is on screen. how can I know for sure when the view is on screen?
Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About how to check if the view is visible, try with this:

[How to tell if UIViewController's view is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777438/how-to-tell-if-uiviewcontrollers-view-is-visible/2777460#2777460)

And then do what you were planning on doing, it has sense.