# I have a uiviewcontroller with 2 containers. How can I distinguish from the code in swift which one currently is visible?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have one `UIViewController` with two containers. Each of those containers contains one `UIViewController`. On the parent view controller I have the segmented control that lets user decide which controller should be currently visible:

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var secondView: UIView!
@IBAction func indexChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        firstView.hidden = true
        secondView.hidden = false
    case 1:
        firstView.hidden = false
        secondView.hidden = true
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Now, in each of the two embedded UIViewControllers I have a viewDidLoad function:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    print("first container")
```

and:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    print("second container")
```

and my problem is: when user enters the parent view controller he immediately sees in the console:

```
first container
second container
```

even though only the first container is visible and the second one is not.

I would like to distinguish which container is currently visible, so that when user enters the parent view controller and sees the first container, he should see only `first container` in the console. And after hitting the segmented control he should see `second container`, and so forth.

I tried to add those prints in `viewWillAppear` but they both load at the same time. How should I modify my code to achieve such effect?

Comment: Have you tried with `viewDidAppear()`? View are loaded before they are shown, and it's default behaviour that your segmented controller loads them at startup.

Comment: Hey, thanks, I just tried with `viewDidAppear` but the behavior is the same - it loads both at once and then nothing shows up when I switch between containers...

Comment: Maybe you can check on this side: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2777460/1585121

Comment: `hidden` views are `appeared` when loaded?

Comment: @zcui93 yes, in this case apparently it's a real thing :(

Comment: @Mayerz hm it looks promising, but I don't know in which place and on which variables (as in my example) could I use it... could you give me some example?